# How to Delete Repeated Values comparing Two Rows on Mysql

Tags: mysql, rows

i have a Mysql Table (TblModelosProductos), The structure is:

id
codigo
id_modelo

code can have repeated values ​​as long as id_codigo is different

Example:

```
id codigo id_modelo
1   A        1
2   A        1
3   A        1
4   B        2
5   C        2
6   A        2
```

in this example, I must delete ids 2 and 3 and only leave one of the repeated ones (id 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self join on the table for the delete statement:

```
delete t
from tblmodelosproductos t  
inner join tblmodelosproductos tt
on tt.id < t.id and tt.codigo = t.codigo and tt.id_modelo = t.id_modelo
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dwYj8vKRRYuurjJhhnLyEK/0).
Results:

```
| id  | codigo | id_modelo |
| --- | ------ | --------- |
| 1   | A      | 1         |
| 4   | B      | 2         |
| 5   | C      | 2         |
| 6   | A      | 2         |
```

Comment: Really Thanks, Has Worked Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This should get the rows you want. Using the group by gets those rows with 
unique values in the two columns, and the MIN() function gets the lowest value for id in each grou of rows.

```
SELECT
    MIN(`id`) as `id`,
    `codgigo`,
    `id_modelo`
FROM `TblModelosProductos`
GROUP BY `codgigo`, `id_modelo`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delet NOT IN based subquery for min id

```
delete from my_table 
where id not in (

  select select min(id)
  from my_table 
  group by id_model 

)
```